# Google Calendar API: User exists as an attendee when the meeting does not exist in his calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I'm using calendar API to pull events of users in an organization that had installed my GSuite app as a service account (it just means that I have access to all the users in the organization).

I noticed some weird behavior - let's say I have an event with 2 participants - a and b (both are users in the company). when I use the calendar API events.list to pull event for a I get this event, and b is listed in the attendee list with responseStatus of 'accepted'.
When I pull the events for the same period of time for user b, I do not get this meeting, nor when I try to pull a specific event using the meeting id (event.get API). I also used showDeleted=True but still didn't get the event back when pulling the events of b (I'm pretty sure if the event would have been deleted then the responseStatus would have been 'decline').

What could be the reason for this behavior? I tried to reproduce it using two emails that I have access to, and I was not successful.
Since those are emails of my client I cannot just come up to them and ask what happened with this meeting.

This is the request I'm making (using python google API client):

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build as Build  

service = Build("calendar", "v3", credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False)
service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=min_time, timeMax=max_time, pageToken=page_token, singleEvents=True).execute()
```

First I'm building the service using the service account credentials (delegating permissions to the current email), and then making the request to pull the events. 
The `min_time,max_time` are strings like this - `2020-10-19T08:00:00+0000`. 
The `pageToken` starts as `None` but will change if there is a `nextPageToken` in the response.

This is the request I made to try and get the meeting of the user that appear as an attendee when pulling the event using another user's email & credentials: 
`service.events().get(calendarId='primary', eventId=<meeting_id>).execute()` 
But I'm getting 404 event not found response (This API returns deleted events - I've seen it)

I'm pulling all of the events correctly, and only saw this case on small number of the events (less than 5% of the meetings).

Any idea what could cause this?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you share the santised request body?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo - This is an example of the requests I'm making (I use python google API client), but this is the raw query (in here I do not retrieve the deleted events):
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?timeMin=2020-10-19T08%3A00%3A00%2B0000&timeMax=2020-10-19T10%3A00%3A00%2B0000&singleEvents=true&alt=json

Comment: Can you edit your question with the actual request object? I do not have your API key so get a 403 error, and trailing through the URL is a little clunky and awkward

Comment: @RafaGuillermo - I've edited the question to include the code I'm using to retrieve the calendar events.

Comment: Can you confirm if user b has accepted the invite to the event? Or are they just an invitee?